# Prevent writeDataTable (openxlsx) from writing any column names

Tags: openxlsx

When writing a table to an Excel workbook:

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Data")
data <- tibble(x = seq(1,10), y = c("A","B","C","D", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
writeDataTable(wb, sheet = "Data", x = data, colNames = FALSE, withFilter = FALSE, tableStyle = "none")
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Temp.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Even when `colNames = FALSE`, names are written - it's just that the actual column names are replaced by "Column1", "Column2" etc.

Is there a way to get writeDataTable to write the table and completely omit the column names - so that the first data value in the data.frame is written at A1 (or wherever specified), not "Column1"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the solution is a bit trivial - use `writeData` not `writeDataTable`.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Data")
data <- tibble(x = seq(1,10), y = c("A","B","C","D", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
writeData(wb, sheet = "Data", x = data, colNames = FALSE, withFilter = FALSE, tableStyle = "none")
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "Temp.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I didn't realise the `writeDataTable` function is specifically for writing Excel tables - as opposed to what I thought (just generally writing tables of data).