# How to use write.table to download a dataframe into a nice csv/Excel file?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, shiny, download

I am trying to use the `write.table()` function, within Shiny `downloadHandler()`, to download the `df` reactive dataframe as a .csv file, per the reproducible code at the bottom. Function `write.table()` allows the dropping of column names (which I need) but results in non-Excel output (**Issue #1**); `write.csv()` on the other hand results in nice Excel output but does not allow the dropping of column names (**Issue #2**).

Is there a way to get `write.table()` to work properly for CSV? If not, is there any other way to resolve this?

This image shows the issues:

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <-
  fluidPage(fluidRow(
    column(width = 8,
           h3("Click below to download:"),
           downloadButton("sumsDownload","Download",style = "width:20%;"),
           h3("Summed Data:"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("sums")
          )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Period = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"),
      ColA = c(1000.01, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
      ColB = c(15.06, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65)
    )
  })
  
  summed_data <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      group_by(!!sym("Period")) %>%
      select("ColA", "ColB") %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum))
  })
  
  output$sums <- renderDT({datatable(data = summed_data(),rownames = FALSE)})
  
  df <- reactive({ # `df` modifies `summed_data` for csv download
    as.data.frame(
      rbind(
        c("Summed Data",rep(NA,ncol(summed_data())-1)),
        colnames(summed_data()),
        matrix(unlist(summed_data(), use.names=FALSE),
               nrow = nrow(summed_data()),
               )
          )
      )
  })
  
  output$sumsDownload <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("sumsDownload","csv",sep=".")},
    content = function(file){
      write.table( # change this to write.csv to see Issue #2
        df(),
        na = "", 
        file, 
        col.names = FALSE, # comment out this line if changing to write.csv
        row.names = FALSE)
      }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at `openxlsx`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670672/prevent-writedatatable-openxlsx-from-writing-any-column-names

Comment: try adding sep=“,” to write.table. As seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750546/export-csv-without-col-names

Comment: It depends on your location (default settings) what Excel expects as the separator. In the US it is a comma in e.g. Germany it is a semicolon (as comma is used as the decimal separator).

Comment: road_to_quantum, that fixed it. I did look at the post you reference beforehand but I rushed through it, I thought that the "," referred to the filename where I already had ".". Lesson learned! Read carefully.

Comment: Hi ismirsehregal, I am running a US version of Windows as I develop code for this project. Now I'll need to run all of my code on UK and EUR versions of Windows and see what blows up. It'll only get harder to debug as the beast grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is resolved code reflecting comments posted through 05 May 2022:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <-
  fluidPage(fluidRow(
    column(width = 8,
           h3("Click below to download:"),
           downloadButton("sumsDownload","Download",style = "width:20%;"),
           h3("Summed Data:"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("sums")
          )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      Period = c("2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"),
      ColA = c(1000.01, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
      ColB = c(15.06, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65)
    )
  })
  
  summed_data <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      group_by(!!sym("Period")) %>%
      select("ColA", "ColB") %>% summarise(across(everything(), sum))
  })
  
  output$sums <- renderDT({datatable(data = summed_data(),rownames = FALSE)})
  
  df <- reactive({ # `df` modifies `summed_data` for csv download
    as.data.frame(
      rbind(
        c("Summed Data",rep(NA,ncol(summed_data())-1)),
        colnames(summed_data()),
        matrix(unlist(summed_data(), use.names=FALSE),
               nrow = nrow(summed_data()),
               )
          )
      )
  })
  
  output$sumsDownload <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("sumsDownload","csv",sep=".")},
    content = function(file){
      write.table( 
        df(),
        na = "", 
        file, 
        sep = ",", # add this per road_to_quantdom on May/05/22
        col.names = FALSE, 
        row.names = FALSE)
      }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```